# special methods - Python

Tags: python, methods

I am learning about special methods in Python. I understand the double underscore syntax for special methods - as per the example below.

However - when reading someone else's code, how does one know, in general, that e.g. the double underscored `getitem` definition opens up the `[]` indexing functionality (vs. e.g. a hypothetical getitem() functionality), and that e.g. the doubled underscored `len` definition opens up the `len()` ability? Is it possible to use e.g. help functions to understand this?

```
import collections

Card = collections.namedtuple('Card', ['rank', 'suit'])

class FrenchDeck:
    ranks = [str(n) for n in range(2, 11)] + list('JQKA')
    suits = 'spades diamonds clubs hearts'.split()

    def __init__(self):
        self._cards = [Card(rank, suit) for suit in self.suits
                                        for rank in self.ranks]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._cards)

    def __getitem__(self, position):
        return self._cards[position]

deck=FrenchDeck()
print(len(deck))
print(deck.__len__())

print(deck.__getitem__(4))
print(deck[4])
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__

Comment: Double underscores are not special syntax; they're just conventional names. They are only special because the interpreter is defined to use those functions as defined. If you defined your own function, for example, `__myfunction__`, it would have no more special meaning than if you had called it `myfunction`. The only difference is that names beginning and ending with `__` are reserved for the interpreter; `__foo__` has no special meaning now, but there's no guaranteed that it won't in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the help function would work. You could also look up the [documentation of the base object](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) and have a look at all built-in `__`-functions. For example:

> ```
> object.__len__(self)
> ```
>
> Called to implement the built-in function `len()`. Should return the length of the object, an integer `>= 0`. Also, an object that doesn’t
>   define a `__nonzero__()` method and whose `__len__()` method returns zero
>   is considered to be false in a Boolean context.